# Cloning HDD containing /boot and LVM to new HDD

Tags: linux, lvm, disk-cloning

I am trying to clone the drive below to a new drive of a bigger size:

```
sda                                  8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1                               8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                               8:2    0 223.1G  0 part 
  ├─vg1-root                       254:0    0   200G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg1-home_cachepool_cdata       254:1    0    23G  0 lvm  
  │ └─vg1-home                     254:4    0   3.7T  0 lvm  /home
  └─vg1-home_cachepool_cmeta       254:2    0    20M  0 lvm  
    └─vg1-home                     254:4    0   3.7T  0 lvm  /home
```

(`/dev/sda1` is the BIOS boot partition mounted on `/boot`.)

Can I just do a `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sd[NEW DRIVE] bs=4096`? Or do I have to do something with the LVM partition?

Comment: How full are the drives? It might be a waste to spend time (& possible SSD lifetime writes) copying empty / free space, could just re-create a similar partition & lvm layout & copy the contents

Comment: The LVM partition on the drive has about 60GB but it contains the OS and it's a pain in the butt to reinstall

Comment: 60G is a lot smaller than the entire drive's 223G, I'd just try and re-create two similar sized partitions (first 500G, then second taking up all the extra space, it'd be bigger than the original), then make similar (with some larger) lvm volumes in the large partition, mount each & copy over the data. The end effect should be almost the same as Guy's answer, but with less copying of free space, and perhaps different partition UUID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` will handle the LVM just fine.

Make sure your boot loader points to the right drive on your clone, otherwise it won't boot.

Finally, you will need to resize the LVM on the clone.
Technically you should be able to enlarge a logical volume without a problem while it is mounted, but I suggest doing all operations of this nature on unmounted drives.

`lvresize -L <new size>G --resizefs MyLVGroup/myvol`

will resize the partition and the filesystem at the same time. Tip: add `+` right before `<new size>` in the above command to extend by that amount instead of resizing to it.

To extend the logical volume separately from resizing the filesystem do the following:

`lvresize -L +<amount to extend>G MyLVGroup/myvol`

Then expand the filesystem with:

`resize2fs /dev/MyLVGroup/myvol`

Look at [askubuntu's Q "How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume) and [archwiki's LVM - Volume Operations](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM#Volume_operations) for more information on resizing the LVM.

Comment: BTW, the second link (from archlinux.org) is more complete and informative, but it is also denser. I recommend reading both.

Comment: +1, especially to the archwiki link (the second one), arch generally has excellent info there

Comment: @xen2050 thank you.  Should I generally use the `(link)` syntax without the `[]`, so users see the link instead of some other value?

Comment: I don't think there's a set rule, if the URL is descriptive enough I try and leave them as-is, like just a plain https://superuser.com without any brackets (fyi, stackexchange seems to automatically expand Q links to their titles if it's on the same site), but it seems to happen pretty frequently that someone else will try to edit a plain URL into something *they think* is "more descriptive", so a preemptive description is usually ok too. Can always roll back edits on your own stuff you don't like too

Comment: Great.  Thank you for the advice!